# how to install javax.microedition.lcdui package into Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, midp, lcdui

I am using NetBeans 6.9.1. When I try to

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Command;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.CommandListener;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Image;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.ImageItem;
```

he message `"package javax.microedition.lcdui does not exist"` comes up.
how to solve it?(J2ME application)
tnx.

Comment: you just need to configure WTK with nb.

Comment: [Check this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iOQ0Zho4c4)

Comment: what is WTK?how to configure it?

Comment: Are u using netbeans mobility pack?

Comment: using NetBeans IDE 6.9.1 (Full)

Comment: Which WTK you are using?

Comment: I don't know what is WTK!I'm beginner

Comment: @Jigar: the link may be helpful, but unlabeled links to YouTube can be dangerous, NSFW etc. It would be more helpful if you say what it is.

Answer (score 1):

First be sure that Java ME pack is installed correctly to your Netbeans IDE. To check this go to Tools>Plugins>Installed Tab. And also check if it is Active>[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved that problem by changing the default platform for J2ME. First, I remove platform for J2ME, then I add new platform for J2ME as Sun Java(TM) Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 for CLDC

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

1. download `midp-2.1.jar` in `java_ME_platform_SDK_8.0\lib`
2. in Netbeans right click on the project name and choose set configuation custumize
3. click on Libraries and add JAR/FOLDER
4. browse to `midp_2.1` and open and ok

Answer (score 0):

Download midp-2.1.jar in java_ME_platform_SDK_8.0\lib
in `Netbeans`. Right click on the project name and choose set configuration customize. Click on Libraries and add JAR/FOLDER. Browse to midp_2.1 and click open and ok.